# Racket: no value found for key in hasheq error

Tags: hashtable, racket

As a part of servlet written in Racket, I would like to make a function that converts request bindings (in the form of a hasheq-table with strings as keys and values) to SQL table row (written again as a hasheq-table with strings as keys and sql types as values). It all seems to work as expected up to the point when the function in question receives the two hash tables, at which point it fails with the following error:

The request bindings are:

```
'#hasheq(("lastname" . "Smith")
         ("firstname" . "John")
          ("birthdate" . "1900-10-25"))
```

The column types are

```
'#hasheq(("lastname" . "character varying")
         ("firstname" . "character varying")
         ("birthdate" . "date"))
```

The error message is:

```
Servlet (@ /<... servlet URL ...>) exception:
hash-ref: no value found for key
  key: "lastname"
```

Curiously, if these hash tables are pasted to the DrRacket prompt together with the relevant code fragment, it runs without error producing

```
The value "Smith" needs to be converted to type "character varying"
The value "John" needs to be converted to type "character varying"
The value "1900-10-25" needs to be converted to type "date"
```

What did I do wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is the code:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define bindings-hash
  '#hasheq(("lastname" . "Smith")
           ("firstname" . "John")
           ("birthdate" . "1900-10-25")))

(define types-hash
  '#hasheq(("lastname" . "character varying")
           ("firstname" . "character varying")
           ("birthdate" . "date")))

(define (test)
  (eprintf "The request bindings are \n~v\n" bindings-hash)
  (eprintf "The column types are \n~v\n" types-hash)
  (for ([(this-key this-value) (in-hash bindings-hash)])
    (eprintf "The value ~v needs to be converted to type ~v\n"
             this-value
         (hash-ref types-hash this-key))))

(test)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `hash-equal` when you work with strings. Symbols are guaranteed to work with `eq?`, but strings must be compared with `equal?`.

The problem is that the result of `(eq? "foo" "foo")` is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Do you mean that I should use a different type of equality test or a different type of hash? I don't really have any place in the code that would rely on the equality test. I used "string=?" to compare strings. Is it not the same as "eq?" for strings?

Comment: A different type of hash. Your keys are strings, so you should use `hash-equal`.

Comment: Thank you! I used (make-hasheq) to create all the hash tables. Should I use (make-hasheqv) instead?

Comment: Yes. That or `make-hash-equal`.

Comment: Unfortunately neither one helped: (make-hash-equal) gives: make-hash-equal: unbound identifier in module
  in: make-hash-equal
... and (make-hasheqv) gives the same error as the (make-hasheq) that I originally used.

Comment: Oh! I see that I wrote `make-hash-equal` instead of `make-hash`. Sorry.

Comment: YES!!! using (make-hash) finally fixed it! The remaining mystery is why it produced different behavior in the servlet and on the DrRacket prompt. (Sorry I don't know how to give you a point for the answer -- thank you!)

Comment: You are welcome. To accept the answer click on the mark below the up and down vote. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

This is an actual answer -- to the other part of your question: Why it worked pasting code to the REPL in DrRacket?

The multiple uses of the string literal `"lastname"` are getting "interned" to be the same Racket object in memory. As a result, they are `eq?`:

```
(eq? "lastname" "lastname")
=> #t
```

But in your real servlet program, the string values in the hashes came from two different Racket objects in memory, even if they happened to have the same value. For instance let's construct a string with the value `"lastname"` by way of `(string-append "last" "name")`. If we compare *that* to the string literal `"lastname"` they're *not* `eq?`

```
(eq? "lastname" (string-append "last" "name"))
=> #f
```

They're not the same object in memory, so they're *not* `eq?`. The two different objects do have the same value, so they *are* `equal?`.

Answer (score 2):

*[This is really just a comment on the excellent answer posted by @soegaard. I'm posting it as an "answer" only to get decent mult-line code formatting.]*

To make a hash that compares keys using `equal?`, you can use

```
#hash([key0 . value0]
      [key1 . value1])
```

You can also create the exact same thing by saying

```
(hash key0 value0
      key1 value1)
```

Provided you're splitting it over lines, the grouping of pairs is just as clear, but without all the extra parentheses and dots.

The first way is more traditional and looks like a classic association list. I find myself preferring the second style.